# Dynamically filtering a List View based on user login and field drop down selection

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2013

I have a question that I haven't been able to find the exact answer to. We currently have a list within SharePoint 2013 that User1 will be entering data into. Once this data is in the list an e-mail will be sent to certain users based on a selection in the "Provider" drop down field that User1 selects. (For example, if User1 selections "User2" as the Provider then User2 will get an e-mail that there is new data for them in the list.)

Once the e-mail goes out User2 and User3 will then visit the same list to complete the rest of the needed information.

My question is: How do I create a view of the list to only show data that has User2 in the "Provider" drop down if User2 is visiting the list, while at the same time making it so User1 can see everything within the list? Since User2 is not the creator or modifier of the data (yet), I am not sure how to do this.

Our SP site is connected to our AD, and I can make it so the dropdown for "Provider" has the exact names of the User2 and User3 logins. I tried filtering the list for when Provider = [Me] but it didn't work as plan, as I suspect it is taking [Me] as text.

I am pretty new to SP Designer, so if there is a solution in SP Designer I would appreciate as much info and patience as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Provider field is a Person field then

```
Provider = [Me]
```

will achieve exactly what you've set out to do.  So you have one view (perhaps the default) that filters on Provider = [Me] and one view that shows all items, then the user that performs data entry can switch to the all items view to see everything.  Alternatively you can create one view that has a filer of

```
Provider = [Me] or Modified By = [Me]
```

Which will show any items you created or that are assigned to you.  These filter can be specified when creating a view in the browsed, no need for SP Designer, here's an example - http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2009/07/16/creating-a-custom-view-that-filters-on-the-current-user.aspx

As you physically typing in the usernames into a text field?  That's the only explanation I can think of why the filter might not be working.  Let me know your thoughts but you should be able to get this working.

Comment: ebooyens, thank you for your reply. Would there be a way to limit **1** view to show the providers only their items while showing the User1 **ALL** files? I honestly don't know why I overlooked the field type of Person or Group, but it's exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. Provider = [Me] (like you said) OR Created By = [Me]

Comment: Sounds like you've got it, please let me know if that works for you!

Comment: ebooyens, it looks like i need to change the filtering a little bit. I want **1** view that when user2 or user3 are viewing, they will only see the files that have their names in the Provider field. Yet when any other user is logged in, they will see every file. Is this possible within 1 view? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I don't think so, there are two things I can suggest:  First is to perhaps set up a webpart on the Homepage, or a different page for that matter, that defaults to one view, then when you visit the library itself then that defaults to a different view.  Alternatively we have used this once before bit it's a little buggy - http://spviewpermission.codeplex.com/  Effectively that allows you to control which users have permission to which views, something that SharePoint doesn't natively do. I see there's a similar one here but haven't tried it myself - https://spcolumnpermission.codeplex.com/

Comment: I appreciate the response. Disappointing that SharePoint doesn't allow this OOB. My company would like all Users to visit the same page, yet the page would limit the view based on the user.